# How add eventhandler to button from post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, events

How add eventhandler to custom button, which by added in wordpress article from article editor? How to do it?

Comment: Not sure about wordPress, but if you can write JS, try `button.addEventListener('click', function(){...})`

Comment: adding eventListener to buttons coming from post is same as adding any other buttons in your HTML. The only thing you need to do in editor is add a class or ID to your button from WP editor and then assign eventListener to that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See there are two ways for this, As you have added button from the editor you need to add function in button's click event or you have to provide a class to that button for which function will be defined in jquery already.

For Example.

```
  $('#eins_audiotrigger').bind('click', function() {
    if($('#eins_audiotarget').hasClass('fadeInUp') === false){
        $('#eins_audiotarget').removeClass().addClass('fadeInUp');
    }
    else {
        $('#eins_audiotarget').removeClass().addClass('fadeOutDown');   
    }
});
```